# Erro ao compilar o projeto no Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Esta me dando a seguinte mensagem de erro ao compilar meu projeto e não estou conseguindo resolver

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma ajuda se alguem ja teve esse problema

Comment: Guilherme, seria legal colocar o erro como texto, porque algumas pessoas não conseguem ver imagens (como eu) por causa de proxies e etc...

Comment: onde está o log do erro?

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema ainda essa semana.

Consegui resolver indo em:

File > Settings > Gradle > na parte de `Gradle VM Option` coloque `-Xmx256m` (se quiser aumentar, fique a vontade. Em meu Android Studio deixei como `-Xmx3g`, por exemplo)